# How to set an animation duration according to a timer I have in Android Studio?

Tags: animation, countdowntimer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <rotate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:toDegrees="360" />

</set>
```

this is the xml file for my animation. my animation pauses after the duration is over then rotates again. I want it to rotate clockwise continuously smoothly like a fan nonstop until the tier countdown is over. I have the count down timer ready, my question is how do I set the that same duration of the timer to my animation?

```
 private void startTimer() {
        millisInFuture = mTimeLeftInMillis;
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
                final long millisPassed = millisInFuture - mTimeLeftInMillis;
                progress = (int) (millisPassed * 100 / millisInFuture);
                pb.setProgress(progress);
                pb2.setProgress(0);
                pb3.setProgress(0);
}
}
}
```

the code above is that of my timer

Comment: so do you want to restart the Animation ?
do you want to dynamically edit the animation ?

Comment: if I remove the "repeatMode" tag will it rotate nonestop? Look what I want exactly is that once the timer starts the animation to start as well but I want it to rotate continuously like a spinner or a fan would do. No pauses, just continuous rotation.

Comment: do you want to be infinite animation ? ?

Comment: until the timer stops.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onFinish() {
       view.setAnimation(null);// this will remove Animation
}
```